# Where is spreadsheet with data

Tags: google-app-maker

Is it possible to access the Google drive table as which contains the data for an app maker model? I mean - is it possible to open it as a Spreadsheet?

Comment: You can use the data model export function from the developer environment, or if you need app users to have this capability then you need to implement a custom server script that can be accessed via a button click or similar. A heads up, the built in export function does not export any drive table relations at this time. With a custom script you can export relations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use a spreadsheet as a datasource. I used a simple spreadsheet just to collect 3 items. I was playing with the Email Sender tutorial and I wanted to collect a list of the emails I'd already sent.  I created the fields and went into the  datasources tab and added this code to the queryRecords() function.

```
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('id');
var sh=ss.getSheetByName('RecentEmails');
var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn());
var vA=rg.getValues();
var reRecords=[];
for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
  var reRecord=app.models.RecentEmails.newRecord();
  reRecord.Recipient=vA[i][0];
  reRecord.Date=vA[i][1].toString();
  reRecord.Message=vA[i][2];
  reRecords.push(reRecord);
}
return reRecords;
```

The above function loads the datasource.

Then I connected a table upto the datasource and the data will update whenever the page is loaded.

I loaded the data into the table with a function like this:

```
function archiveSentEmails(to,when,what)
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('id');
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('RecentEmails');
  sh.appendRow([to,when,what]);
}
```

It gets placed inside the serverside script where the MailApp.sendMail function is located.

When you push the Send EMail button it calls this clientside function which calls the serverside function via google.script.run.

```
function sendMessage(to, subject, msg){
  var status = app.pages.Email.descendants.EmailStatus;
  google.script.run
   .withFailureHandler(function(error) {
      // An error occurred, so display an error message.
      status.text = error.message;
    })
  .withSuccessHandler(function(result) {
     // Report that the email was sent.
    status.text = 'Email sent...';
    clearEmailForm();
    loadDebugElements();
    app.datasources.RecentEmails.load();//this lines refreshes the widgets attached to the datasource

   })
 .sendEmailMessage(to, subject, msg);
}
```

and I placed the command `app.datasources.RecentEmails.load` in the withSuccessHandler so that the table of recent emails will update everytime it sends an email and that way you don't have to have a button to initiate updating the table after every email is sent.